# Get Alfresco folder NodeRef using SearchService, LANGUAGE_CMIS

Tags: web-services, alfresco, cmis, alfresco-webscripts, opencmis

I have a java backed webscript. I use `SearchService` method to get the `NodeRef` of a folder stored in the Alfresco repository in this `PATH`:

```
/app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:models\
```

I used the `LANGUAGE_CMIS_STRICT` in the searchService method like this:

```
NodeRef activeModelRepositoryNodeRef=searchService.query(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE, 
                    SearchService.LANGUAGE_CMIS_STRICT, "select * cmis:objectId where contains ('PATH:\"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:models\"')").getNodeRef(0);
```

to get the nodeRef of `models` folder but i still getting this error in my log when i execute my query:

> ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-8080-exec-19]
>   Exception from executeScript: line 1:9 mismatched input
>   'cmis:objectId' expecting FROM  ([@4,9:21='cmis:objectId',<37>,1:9])
>   in fromClause

Can anybody tell me what i made wrong, or telle me how to get a folder `NodeRef` by using `LANGUAGE_CMIS_STRICT` in `SearchService` query (I don't want to use the `LANGUAGE_LUCENE`).
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct:

```
select * from cmis:objectId
```

The from clause should contain a valid type, like cmis:document or a custom type.

Maybe you meant something like:

```
select cmis:objectId from cmis:document
```

But I should also add that will return the CMIS Object ID, not the Alfresco node reference. Those are two different things, although they may look similar.

If you really want the Alfresco node ref look for a property called alfcmis:nodeRef.

Answer (score 2):

You're simply missing FROM keyword.

```
select * FROM cmis:objectId
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, i added `FROM`, but i still get this error:  `org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisInvalidArgumentException: Type is unsupported in query: cmis:objectId`. Have you any idea how i get this error?

Comment: Share your alfresco version and alfresco log.

Comment: Look at @jeffpotts answer below for a complete answer.